# Combine two click functions into one function

Tags: jquery, forms, function, element

I have this script working as I want to, but I'd like to know how I would combine the two click functions into one to make it a better script.

My jsfiddle link: jsfiddle.net/squirc77/BFZju/

thank you!

Comment: Please reference the following link: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). It's okay to use ***jsfiddle*** for demos but it's usually frowned to just post a link with no code in your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add a class to both of the *'radio inputs'* so that when either one of them is clicked, the script will run.

```
$('.myClass').click(function() {
    if ($('#ind').is(':checked')) { 
      $('#ind_text').removeClass('grey');
      $('#chk_ind').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
      $('#ind_text').addClass('grey');
      $('#chk_ind').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Tomer123/BFZju/2/) for demo